# Laravel initial page load is very slow because of duplicate queries it runs in order to get the correct translations

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel for my website and it is very slow. I have a lot of translations on my website and I discovered through Laravel's debugbar that my site runs a lot of duplicate queries to get its translations which, after some testing, is the biggest speed issue.

To get the correct translation, I run this line in my blade:

```
{!! Translation::getString('translation_slug') !!}
```

that calls this function:

```
//TranslationHelper.php
public static function getString(string $string, array $variables = null) : string
{
    if ($variables) {
        $variables = array_map('strval', $variables);
        $variables = array_flip($variables);
        $variables = preg_filter('/^/', ':', $variables);
        $variables = array_flip($variables);
    }
    $translatable = Translatable::where('slug', $string)->first();
    if ($translatable) {
        $language = Session::get("language");
        if ($language) {
            if ($variables) { 
                return strtr($translatable->getTranslation($language), $variables);
            } else {
                return $translatable->getTranslation($language);
            }
        } else {
            if ($variables) { 
                return strtr($translatable->getTranslation('en'), $variables);
            } else {
                return $translatable->getTranslation('en');
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $string; // not found
    }
}
```

As you can see it runs the getTranslation function from the Translatable model:

```
//Translatable.php
public function getTranslation(string $language) {
    $lang = Language::where('shortcode', $language)->first();
    if ($lang) $translation = Translation::where('language_id', $lang->id)->where('translatable_id', $this->id)->first();
    else $translation = Translation::where('language_id', 2)->where('translatable_id', $this->id)->first();
    
    if ($translation == null || !$translation || !$lang) {
        $translation = Translation::where('language_id', 2)->where('translatable_id', $this->id)->first();

        if ($translation) return strip_tags($translation->value, '<br><a><b><i><p><ul><li><strong><del><em><u>');
        else return $this->slug;
    }
    else return strip_tags(Translation::where('language_id', $lang->id)->where('translatable_id', $this->id)->first()->value, '<br><a><b><i><p><ul><li><strong><del><em><u>');
}
```

I've looked into Laravel Cache and managed to cache the Language models like this:

```
    $languages = Cache::rememberForever('languages', function() {
        return Language::all();
    });
    $lang = $languages->where('shortcode', $language)->first();
```

This significantly lowered the duplicate queries it made but when I tried the same for the translation models like this:

```
    $translations = Cache::rememberForever('translations', function() {
        return Translation::all();
    });
    if ($lang) $translation = $translations->where('language_id', $lang->id)->where('translatable_id', $this->id)->first();
```

Laravel gives a fatal error:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

The lines where I run `Translation::where` gives hundreds of duplicate queries. I have a total of 6246 different translation entries so i'm guessing it has something to do with that. Did i make a mistake or is there maybe a better way to refactor this code and to get rid of the duplicate queries and improve my website's speed?

Comment: you could have separate cache entries per language for the translations, i would only be pulling the ones for a specific language instead of getting all of them then filtering them

Comment: @lagbox Maybe tag each translation, with the tag derived from the language - that way each one can retain the same key for the same translation

Comment: OP, do your translations need to be in the database at all? The default Laravel translation functionality depends on having the translations in PHP files, and unless it's for something like a CMS where it needs to be editable by a non-technical user I'd go for that route

Comment: @MatthewDaly they need to be in the database because the translations can be edited in the cms

Comment: Shouldn't your `$variables` preparation be `if ($variables) {
        $variables = array_combine(array_map(fn($v) => ':' . strval($v), $variables), $variables);
    }`